# Navigate on clickable Imagebutton

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

I have an ImageButton1 and ImageButton1_Click event. The Image is clickable, and when i click on it the Event fires up...

Doing this works:

```
Response.Redirect("secondPage.aspx");
```

But, I would like to load it with :

```
ImageButton1.NavigationUr = "some url";
```

how can I have a dynamic link?

Comment: When you need to assign the url? At start or when performing any action on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the ImageButton1.DescriptionUrl property. Set the url on runtime and redirect using the below code.

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(ImageButton1.DescriptionUrl);
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work. For some reason, the page realoads so I get the next dynamic item, and navigates to it.... really strange!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the HyperLink control would fit:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="whatever" runat="server" ImageUrl="/foo.png" NavigateUrl="some url" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use firebug to find the exact id and attributes that are being set on the imagebutton (or set a cssClass for client-side access ease), and then use javascript or jquery to set the navigation attribute when you need to.